# Error while installing Age of Empire 2 HD edition- PlayOnLinux

Tags: games, playonlinux

i get this when i try to install Age of Empire II HD edition with PlayOnLinux app

im using Ubuntu 18.04.02 LTS Bionic

[image]

Comment: Do you have Steam installed?  It appears to be trying to launch the Windows version of Steam.  Also, if you have Age of Empires II HD in your Steam library, have you tried running it with the Linux version of Steam and proton?

Comment: opss no ive linux version of steam installed. and Age of Empire II is not in my library.
ok i will install windows version of steam, but must i've bought the game from steam to install it this way ?